# Compiling razor views on TFS build server (2012)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, tfs

I want to configure our TFS build-server so it will compile my views and notify me about compile errors.

This is my configuration:

```
    <Target Name="BuildViews" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'"  AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Message Importance="normal" Text="Precompiling views" />
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Unfortunately I am getting these errors. The AspNetCompiler does not recognize any the MVC syntax such as model or the HTML helper. What can be wrong, there is a /bin director in the $(WebProjectOutputDir)

```
d:\TfsBuildCache\1\Episerver7\trunk\Assemblies\_PublishedWebsites\Pdk.Website\Views\ActionStart\Index.cshtml (3): The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Is MVC installed on the build server?

Comment: Install MVC4? Should be in the /bin folders what do you mean?

Comment: Your build server should be set up almost exactly like a developer machine, including the software loadout used to develop your applications. If you had to install MVC 4 on your local environment, you'll need to install it on the build server as well.

Comment: I have aspNet 4.5 installed on TFS. I just get weird errors.. Such as D:\TfsBuildCache\1\Episerver7\trunk\src\Pdk.Website\Pdk.Website.csproj (1436): The TargetPath parameter must be specified if the target directory needs to be overwritten.